# there does not exist an injective function whose codomain is smaller than its domain

Tags: functions, proof-verification, pigeonhole-principle

I encountered this theorem on [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)
*"there does not exist an injective function whose codomain is smaller than its domain".*
Here is my attempt to prove it, can you please have a look if this proof is OK?

**Proof**:
Let's say we have:
$f:A\to B$
where $|A| = N$ and $|B| = M$.
Let's take all elements from $A$:

$ a_1,\cdots ,a_N $
and by mapping them, we get:

$f(a_1),\cdots , f(a_N)$.

There can't exist two same elements in latter list (according to injection).
Which means there need to be at least N distinct elements in B. This can't hold if $M < N$.

Answer (score 1):

The continuous case is not true, $f(x) = x/2$ for $0\le x\le 1$, so you really need the assumption that the domain is a finite set.

Given a finite set as domain, I think your proof is OK.

Comment: thanks I was assuming finite case, but I will give thought to your continuous case.

Comment: @Pieter21 $(0,1)$ and $(0,1/2)$ have the same cardinality so in that sense the statement still holds true in the infinite case.

Comment: If your size is cardinality this is indeed true. This half length construct was just to demonstrate that we have to be careful of definitions and conditions in the question.